# How to get max value from a list of string values

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list like this:

```
['v_1', 'v_2', 'v_8', 'v_5']
```

How can I get 8 from this list?

Comment: Please show your code. Furthermore, please provide more details on what are the more complex scenarios you plan on matching. Are you going to be dealing with double, triple digits, are they going to be separated by decimals? These details are important. You really need to provide a more concrete [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the strings to numbers easily enough, and just take the maximum. Assuming everything in your list is of the form `"v_#"` where `#` is an integer:

```
m = max(int(x[2:]) for x in my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
max(l, key=lambda s: int(s[2:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `max()` and `str.index()` functions (considering `_` as separator):

```
l = ['v_1', 'v_2', 'v_8', 'v_5']
m = max(v[v.index('_')+1:] for v in l)

print(m)   # 8
```

Answer (score 0):

`max` takes a keyword argument that lets you specify a function to transform each list element before doing the comparisons to find the largest.

Compare the following:

```
# Lexicographically, `v_8` is bigger than `v_12`
>>> max(['v_1', 'v_2', 'v_8', 'v_5', 'v_12'])
'v_8'

# Numerically, 12 > 8 after striping the v_ prefix and treating
# the remainder as an integer
>>>>>> max(['v_1', 'v_2', 'v_8', 'v_5', 'v_12'], key=lambda x: int(x[2:]))
'v_12'
```